# Spring MVC web.xml mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I was looking at a tutorial on Spring MVC, and noticed that the dispatcher servlet is mapped to the urlpattern `/`and it was explained that this means that all requests will be handled by the servlet defined to handle that urlpattern.

That makes sense, but I thought that `/*` was the notation used to specify all requests, not just `/`. What is the difference between a url pattern of `/` and one of `/*`? I would think that `/` would map to the context path of the application. so for example, if 'myapp' was the context root of the app:

`myipaddress/myapp` would be handled by a urlpattern of `/`

`myipaddress/myapp/foo` would be handled by a urlpattern of `/*`

Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0):

The url-pattern specification:

> A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix
>   is used for path mapping.
>
> A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
>
> A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"
>   servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>   request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
>
> All other strings are used for exact matches only.

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/